# CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification fires on bluetooth state change

Tags: ios, bluetooth, cellular-network

CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification fires on bluetooth state change i.e whenever, Bluetooth is turned on and off.

How can I make it to detect only cellular state changes.

Any help will be appreciated.